# Scrolling inside a DIV that does not have position:absolute?

Tags: css, html, scroll, css-float

I have a website with 5 horizontal divs whom all float:left and have a % width. The left one I want to have text in, and a scrollbar. However, the scrollbar only shows up when I give it a position:absolute. Try it in the jsfiddle. When I do that, the div ignores the other 4 and they get out of line. How do I work around this?

The jsfiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/QN8RS/
Add position:absolute; to the following div in CSS. You will see it working, but the divs get out of place..

```
#left{
    float:left;
    background-color:#C00;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    top: 0px; 
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: try adding another property `max-height=100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified the height of the `<body>` so its height is computed as `auto`.

You specified the height of `.main` as `100%`. This is a percentage so, because the height of its parent (the body) is computed as `auto`, the computed height is also `auto`.

You specified the height of `#left` as `100%`. This is a percentage so, because the height of its parent (.main) is computed as `auto`, the computed height is also `auto`.

Since the height is `auto`, the height as is tall as it needs to be to hold all the content.

Since you have set `overflow: auto`, you only get scrollbars if the content is taller then the element (which it isn't).

Set `height: 100%` on the html and body elements so that the computed height of `#left` is the height of the viewport and not `auto`.

Comment: Beat me to it :( +1 for being fast with explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for :
`overflow-y: scroll`

[Little Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QN8RS/1/)

Comment: That forces the scrollbar to render, but since there is no difference between the height of the element and the height of the content, it doesn't allow anything to scroll.

Comment: Quentin, but how come it scrolls when I put the overflow on auto and the position on absolute and not now then?! Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have specified `height:100%` on your div `.main`. 100% of what? Which parent?

If you specify the height of body to 100% then it will work.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Check your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QN8RS/2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using floats, use `position: absolute;` and `left: number%;` (you will have to figure out how much % the left is of each element).

Check out the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QN8RS/3/